# Using wsHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, transactions, wcf-binding, wcf-security

After reading more about it and trying to implement wshttpbinding, it just won't happen. No matter what I try, I keep getting the below error message (with security mode commented out). I understand why because of the different SOAP versions between bindings.

"(415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'"

I read more about the TransportWithMessageCredentials at the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789011.aspx

but still could not get it to work.

I can use basicHttpBinding just fine for internal apps and works great (if I don't include any transactions), but my application in the WCF layer still needs to support transactions (see below), from which I understand that basicHttpBinding doesn't support, because it doesn't contain the transactionflow attribute.

```
[OperationContract]

[TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]

using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
```

When I try and run the below with the security mode included, the svc config editor doesn't even start up and throws the following error: "System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]."

I know it's expecting some kind of SSL/https security, but my website (as you can see below is http) . That would be fine for the public facing websites, but for internal sites, for now, all I want to do is have support for transactions.

Here is my server side setup for wsHttpBinding:

```
<bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WsHttpBinding_IYeagerTechWcfService" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transactionFlow="true">
          <security mode="Transport" >
            <transport clientCredentialType = "Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<services>
  <clear />

  <service name="YeagerTechWcfService.YeagerTechWcfService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="YeagerTechWcfService.IYeagerTechWcfService" >
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://abc.com/yeagerte/YeagerTechWcfService.YeagerTechWcfService.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

Here is my client side setup:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://abc.com/yeagerte/YeagerTechWcfService.YeagerTechWcfService.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="YeagerTechWcfService.IYeagerTechWcfService"
    name="WsHttpBinding_IYeagerTechWcfService" />
</client>
```

Could somebody please provide the following:

Is there another way to support transactions in WCF for basicHttpBinding or any other way for that matter?

If so, how do I implement it?

If not, what are my options?

For the above question, I may have figured out an answer but want to run it by somebody more experienced in this matter.

Instead of having the WCF layer handle the transactions (like mentioned above), I propose I use basicHttpBinding and the following code in my Controller when it passes the data to the WCF layer:

```
// method here
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
                        {
                            db.EditCategory(cat);
                           // the above code would execute the EditCategory method below in the WCF layer  and keep the transaction alive                                                   ts.Complete();
                            ts.Dispose();
                        }
                        return Json(new GridModel(db.GetCategories()));
// end method
```

WCF layer:

```
public void EditCategory(Category cat)
        {
            try
            {
              using (YeagerTechEntities DbContext = new YeagerTechEntities())
                {
                    Category category = new Category();

                    category.CategoryID = cat.CategoryID;
                    category.Description = cat.Description;

            // do another db update here or in another method...

                    DbContext.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    DbContext.SaveChanges();
                }
             }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

For public facing websites using SSL, how do I properly implement wsHttpBinding?

Comment: fyi, I tried what I said about the option with using the transactionscope in the Controller and it worked fine with basicHttpBinding.

Any other feedback about this and or the other questions about my previous post would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when using WCF Transactions
I used Message security with Windows authentication and did not have to setup any certificates.

```
<wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_Transactional" 
           transactionFlow="true">
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
 </wsHttpBinding>
```